# Updating from Wordpress 3.5.2 to 3.6 Errors

Tags: updates

When trying to update from 3.5.2 to 3.6 the following error occurs:

```
Warning: touch(): Unable to create file /tmp/wordpress-3.tmp because No such file or directory in /home/yaznetx1/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 179

Warning: unlink(/tmp/wordpress-3.tmp): Operation not permitted in /home/yaznetx1/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 503

Download failed.: Could not open handle for fopen() to /tmp/wordpress-3.tmp

Installation Failed
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The latest stable version of Wordpress is 3.6. Have you got confused somewhere?

Comment: 1.6 is 8 yers ago, what you were doing till now?

Comment: Sounds like a file permission problem.  Try [manually updating](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update).

Comment: You may also want to review this "Troubleshooting WordPress 3.6 Master List" here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-36-master-list?replies=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments guys, I was over on the WPMU and was told to manual update, worked like a charm. Will do that with any issues in the future.